Automating web scraping with Selenium and AWS MWAA
I am relatively new to AWS and am working on a side project to automate some webscraping with Selenium with MWAA on AWS. I havent been able to get past this one problem for days now and am hoping someone here can help.
Essentially when I run my DAG, the webdriver wont initialize and I receive the error posted below. I have tried using specific versions of the ChromeDirverManager, using CHROMIUM instead of Chrome and many other things with no success.
Obviously, for some reason there is no determined browser version but I cannot figure out why. It is my understanding that the webdriver_manager should install the latest version. Is there anything else I need to add to my dependencies? Is there something else entirely I need to do in order to make sure Chrome is installed? Thanks in advance!
Problem code:
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(),
    options=chrome_options)

Error:
[2024-04-04, 23:17:15 UTC] {{taskinstance.py:2698}} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 433, in _execute_task
    result = execute_callable(context=context, **execute_callable_kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 199, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 216, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/local_scraping_dag_cloud.py", line 88, in scrape_bop_sites
    executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(),
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/webdriver_manager/chrome.py", line 40, in install
    driver_path = self._get_driver_binary_path(self.driver)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/webdriver_manager/core/manager.py", line 40, in _get_driver_binary_path
    file = self._download_manager.download_file(driver.get_driver_download_url(os_type))
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/webdriver_manager/drivers/chrome.py", line 32, in get_driver_download_url
    driver_version_to_download = self.get_driver_version_to_download()
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/webdriver_manager/core/driver.py", line 48, in get_driver_version_to_download
    return self.get_latest_release_version()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/webdriver_manager/drivers/chrome.py", line 64, in get_latest_release_version
    determined_browser_version = ".".join(determined_browser_version.split(".")[:3])
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
[2024-04-04, 23:17:15 UTC] {{taskinstance.py:1138}} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=local_scraping_dag_cloud, task_id=task1, execution_date=20240404T231706, start_date=20240404T231710, end_date=20240404T231715
[2024-04-04, 23:17:15 UTC] {{standard_task_runner.py:107}} ERROR - Failed to execute job 32 for task task1 ('NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'; 361)
[2024-04-04, 23:17:16 UTC] {{local_task_job_runner.py:234}} INFO - Task exited with return code 1

I have tried using specific versions of the ChromeDirverManager, using CHROMIUM instead of Chrome and many other things with no success.
